# Adding tooltip for RadioButtonList items

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

My `RadioButtonList` is bound to the database as follows:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ItemsID,ItemsDescription FROM Items", con);
adapter.Fill(subjects);
rblUseCases.DataSource = subjects;
rblUseCases.DataTextField = "ItemsDescription";
rblUseCases.DataValueField = "ItemsID";          
rblUseCases.DataBind();
```

I need to add a new tooltip to be shown when the user hovers around any radio button. I plan to add the tooltip text as a new column `Tooltip` in the database table `Items`. How can I databind this to the radio button?

Answer (score 9):

The following code will show tooltip on the radio button:

```
ListItem li=new ListItem("Manish","oopde");
li.Attributes.Add("title","zello");
RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(li);
```

For databinding you can iterate through each item and add the attributes to it. The databound and databinding event doesn't call for each items because of which we didn't get any other option to implement the same.

Answer (score 3):

after databind write this code:

```
foreach( ListItem itm in rblUseCases.Items)
       {
          itm.Attributes.Add( "title", "value: " + itm.Text);
       }
```

Here itm.Text should be bound from the database.

Comment: it's impossible be easier! +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

[The answer can be found here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/5099-Tool-tip-for-DropDownList-ASP-NET.aspx)

Code from the article:

```
foreach(var item in rblUseCases.items)
{                   
       item.Attributes.Add("Title", rblUseCases.Item[i].Text)
}
```

If you want it to be a value from your adapter, then you will have to manually grab the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    rdoTest.DataSource = new string[]
    {
        "Hello",
        "World",
    }; 

    rdoTest.DataBind();

    foreach (ListItem item in rdoTest.Items)
    {
        item.Attributes["title"] = item.Text;
    }
```

Thanks

Deepu